# Macbook Pro (late 2016) suddenly stopped detecting my external monitor after a 3h hibernation

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

Macbook Pro (late 2016) suddenly stopped detecting my external monitor after a 3h hibernation after working flawlessly for two weeks.

I've verified that [my monitor](https://www.samsung.com/se/monitors/c32hg70/LC32HG70QQUXEN/) works fine with my Windows PC.

I'm running MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 which I updated to August 18th.

I'm using a USB-C to DisplayPort cable which will wake up my monitor from standby mode, but my Macbook Pro still can't detect it. Display in System Preferences gives me nothing and Options revealing Detect Screen doesn't yield any results either.

I've followed the [official troubleshooting](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201177) (including reset of NVRAM and SMC) without results.

I'm guessing that maybe my cable is defective, but then, why would it wake up the monitor?

Comment: Have you tried just disconnecting and reconnecting the monitor?

Comment: @Allan Yes, that was part of the official support docs.

Comment: What cable are you using?  Is it a USB-C adapter or just cable?

Comment: @Allan Just a cable with usbc on one side and display port on the other. I.e. both ends are male.

Comment: If you reboot, does it start to work?

Comment: @Allan No, it's like the monitor is expecting a signal, but the Macbook isn't sending anything. I've tried switching usbc port as well. There are four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by buying a new cable. This cable was a USB-C to HDMI.