# How do I keep my MBP's screen as secondary display even if my external monitor (main display) is off or switched to displaying another computer

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I'm working with 2 different computers and one main 2K monitor, so I use a switcher hub to jump from displaying one computer to displaying the other. The issue us that my MBP, every time I switch away from it in the main display, gathers everything onto its default screen: windows, dock, desktop icons, and it changes the resolution, so that when I switch back to it on the main 2K display it un-gathers everything, sends it back to the main display, but now on the MBP's screen the image looks horrible: pixelated and blurry, so that I need to click on CMD + Lower Brightness 2 times, to switch back and forth from main to secondary display on the MBP for the resolution to go back to what it should be. (Not to mention it leaves an unused screen space at the bottom where the dock used to be.)

This doesn't happen when I simply turn off my 2K monitor. In that case, the MBP remains as just a secondary monitor. Which is why I'm asking this, assuming that there must be a way of forcing my MBP to always be a secondary monitor, no matter what—even if that means that whatever is on my main display is entirely un-reachable if the main display is now showing my other computer.

Comment: It might be the hub, or it might be the other computer. I have a PC connected to the same screen as my Mac, switched from the screen itself. Flipping between the two is fine, but if the PC restarts whilst it is showing on the screen, the Mac does as you describe, shoves everything back to one screen.

Comment: Hi, @Tetsujin! Thanks for your response! That's interesting. I have realised that even though just turning off the external monitor does nothing, disconnecting the HDMI cable does. So I'm assuming the even if the monitor is off, the cable "detects" theres an output, so it keeps the primary display active where it ought. Which is why I'm wondering if there's a way of forcing the system to always act as if there's a primary display connected. (BTW, I've tried out 6 different hubs, thinking they might be the issue, but the result is the same with all 6.)

Comment: A true [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) ought to always make the computer think the monitor is on, connected & working. If it doesn't, that's really a failing of that hardware. I'm not certain whether your hub qualifies as a KVM. My own manual push-button switching I do on my monitor doesn't qualify ;)

Comment: That's good to know. I don't think any of the hubs were KVMs, actually. My keyboard and mouse are from the Logitech master/anywhere line, so they switch automatically when you move the mouse from one side to the other. The first hubs were push-bottom, but the more recent ones work with a 5V power input, and I always keep them on, so I assumed that would keep the HDMI active, as it were. I'll look into getting a true KVM switch to see if that's it. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome. I'm not sure there's really anything I can turn into an answer, tbh. Maybe come back once you've found one that works correctly & back-fill your own answer. That could prove useful to future readers.

Comment: Indeed I will. I'll keep on texting a bit further, and especially trying to find out if one can configure the MBP into "not caring" whether or not there's something connected to the HDMI port or not. Have a great day!

Comment: @Tetsujin is correct re:  the KVM and keeping the connection.  I also recommend *not* using HDMI in this type of setup as it's more AV related than it is for computer graphics.  If you must use HDMI, use an [Active Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271) instead.  The issue you're seeing is because the signal drops or goes  "low" even when connected.