# Mac mini external display connection problem

Tags: display, mac-mini

I was connecting my Mac mini to an external display (HP M24f) by an HDMI cable. The (very) annoying thing was that after some time of inactivity of the computer, the connection between display and computer was broken. Clicking on the mouse or keyboard did not restore any connection. Display was awake but no signal was coming from Mac mini. I saw only screen saver of my external display. This was sporadic and I couldnot link to a particular reason or time of the day. This happened 30-40% of the time when I tried to use my computer after overnight inactivity or few hours. My power nap was on and I never shut off my computer besides once a week or two. Only the way I could restore that HDMI connection was either unpluging and repluging the HDMI cable from either computer or display, or restarting the computer.

Recently, I am connecting an AVR to my MacMini. It’s a Yamaha RX-V675, and I am using it as stereo amplifier and passing the video signal from my MacMini to HP display. An HDMI cable goes from my Mac Mini to AVR from there it goes to my external display. Since I have started using my AVR as middleman between MacMini and display, I have never had the issue I have described in the first paragraph. I am wondering what the reason for the problem and why my AVR solves this problem. Before this, I have returned nicer displays as I thought they were not compatible with my computer.

Comment: [HDMI is great for consumer electronics but horrible for computers.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398441/119271).  If at all possible, use a mDP to HDMI (active) adapter.  What specific Mac mini do you have?

Comment: 2018 Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: @Allan If HDMI is horrible for computers, why the ports are included in the computers?

Comment: It’s what consumers want.

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Currently Ventura.